# Should I create another table column or is there another way I can go about doing this?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm having an issue trying to figure out how to solve this problem.

I have a database with a Table that holds job information. There's a column called "Payments" and the values % per payment term are split up here like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojj4Y.png

So at the bottom the values will read 40%, 40%, 20%.

In the form, these values are displayed exactly the same as in the database, 40/40/20.

I was tasked with creating 4 option boxes instead with values in each ranging from 10% to 100%. Here's what the code looks like.

```
        <label for='payment'>Payment Terms</label>
            <?php
            // Create 4 % boxes that add up to %100 for Payment Terms
            // Must validate and add up to %100
            $selects = 4;
            if (isset($data2['payment'])) {
              $percentages = explode("/", $data2['payment']);
              // Make sure that the array is long enough by adding zeroes to the end
              while (count($percentages) < $selects) $percentages[] = 0;
            }
            else {
              $percentages = array_fill(0, $selects, 0);
            }

            $options = range(10, 100, 10);

            for ($i = 0; $i < $selects; ++$i) { ?>
            <ul style="list-style-type: none;"><li><select id="paymentSelect">
              <option></option>
              <?php foreach ($options as $o) { ?>
                 <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"
                  <?php if ($o == $percentages[$i]) echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>
                    <?php echo $o; ?>
                </option>
              <?php } ?>
            </select></li></ul>
            <?php } ?>
```

This is what the form looks like now: http://i.imgur.com/2OvDtsn.png

The blue date boxes is what I want to create. Will I have to make a new column in my table? How will I link each percentage to each date since the percentages are already in the table?

Comment: Please clarify what the relationship is between this _payment_ column and a set of dates.

Comment: @hanzo2001 The payment column is when each payment is to be received or has been received. The user picks a percentage, say 20%, and picks a date from a jquery date picker of when this payment was received.

Comment: Ok, so now the question is, do you want a new table column? or are you comfortable with saving some formated data into your fields, for example: `40:date/40:date/20:date` **or** `40/40/20|date/date/date`

Comment: I'm fine with saving some formatted data into the fields. Wouldn't creating a new column create some complexity? Especially of the way the data has already been inserted into hundreds of jobs like so `40/40/20` . I like the `40:date/40:date/20:date` example as it's easily readable too. @hanzo2001

Comment: whatch out! you already have **loads** of data inserted into the table. This means that you'll have to take into account that new information may be stored as `P:D/P:D/P:D` while old info will remain. Your handling scripts will have to take this into account, so everything that captures that specific field and manipulates it or outputs it has to be considered. @laxin204 has indead a good answer

Comment: Hmm alright, I'll explore my options more carefully. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a new table in your data base "Payments" and have a foreign key to tie it back to the original table, your payment column and your date column.  Then you can have as many payment percents and Dates you would ever want.

Comment: Would this mean that I would have to transfer all current data to this new table and link it to the correct job id ?

Comment: Yes, you would have to weigh weather that is worth it or not, but it will be the easiest way to tie the correct date to the correct percentage.

Comment: how would I go about doing this efficiently? I only have basic SQL experience. Theres hundreds of different jobs with their own payment terms already. @laxin204

Comment: I would write a script to read the current data, process it and write it back to new table.  The new table should have the following columns `PaymentId`, `JobId`, `Payment`, and `Date`. Each payment field will get it's own row in the new table.

Comment: Okay going to try this out. I just have a question regarding the foreign key. Here's the layout of the table I want to grab this information from. | id | job_id | column2 | column3 | payment | In my new table would I set the job_id as the foreign key or the id? Because whenever a job is edited/revised and saved, a new "id" is created but obviously the job_id stays the same. @laxin204

Comment: Yes job_id is the foreign key, it's how the data is tied together. The primary key would be a new Id for that table auto incremented in case you ever need to make another table off of that one.

Answer (score 0):

I might be tempted to future proof this for 10 options or 20 options or whatever to save always changing the columns in the table. How about you have 4 rows to show your payment terms - pairs for each date and %. If you have multiple possibilities - i.e. several clients with different payment terms then your table should have a client_id. This way you can have some clients with 2 payments, others with 50 - simply by adding rows with fields (client_id, %, date).

Validation is the same and the table much simpler. To retrieve the payment data you are fetching multiple rows that make table building from PHP fairly straightforward too.

Best
Nick

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this "I might be tempted to future proof this for 10 options or 20 options or whatever to save always changing the columns in the table." Mind elaborating? 

I think what you're describing with the 4 rows to show my payment terms and a date corresponding to each row is what I want to do. The issue is that theres already a ton of jobs in this system with payment terms laid out exactly like i've illustrated above.

Comment: Yes - if you use rows then you have the ability to have an arbitrary number of payment dates to describe the payment terms. If you use columns then you are somewhat constrained to the number of payment dates you decided when designing the table. I see what you mean in terms of tying it into what exists already - is that handled by php? When you bring the data in from the db won't you have an array $pterms['clientid']['date']['pcnt']? Could this be matched to code that is looking for a date and a pcnt for a given client?